# Is it possible to declare data type for each column of a Pivoted Table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I happened to have dynamic data with a group of common IDs. So I decided to create a Pivot table for it. Let's say I've a following data in before I create a pivot table.

```html
part_id         data_element          value
------------------------------------------------
part1           part_name             Motor
part1           operator_id           Kishore
part1           shift_id              B
part1           production_count      20
part2           part_name             LVDT
part2           operator_id           Kumar
part2           shift_id              A
part2           production_count      3
```

As you can see in the above table, for a **part1**, I've different **data_elements** and their respective **values**. And I had to make **varchar** as a common data type for value column since value could be anything. And based on this, I created the following pivot table.

```html
part_id  part_name  operator_id  shift_id  production_count
-----------------------------------------------------------
part1    Motor      Kishore      B         20
part2    LVDT       Kumar        A         3
```

Please find pivoting queries I've used to achieve the above pivoted table

```
CREATE VIEW table_view_name AS (
SELECT
 `table_name`.`part_id`,
 `table_name`.`data_element`,
 `table_name`.`value`,
 (CASE WHEN (`table_name`.`data_element` = 'part_name') THEN 
 `table_name`.`value` END) AS `part_name`,
 (CASE WHEN (`table_name`.`data_element` = 'operator_id') THEN 
 `table_name`.`value` END) AS `operator_id`,
 (CASE WHEN (`table_name`.`data_element` = 'shift_id') THEN 
 `table_name`.`value` END) AS `shift_id`,
 (CASE WHEN (`table_name`.`data_element` = 'production_count') THEN 
 `table_name`.`value` END) AS `production_count`
FROM `table_name`)
```

And

```
CREATE VIEW `table_extended_view` AS (
SELECT
  `table_view_name`.`part_id`,
  MAX(`table_view_name`.`part_name`) AS `part_name`,
  MAX(`table_view_name`.`operator_id`) AS `operator_id`,
  MAX(`table_view_name`.`shift_id`) AS `shift_id`,
  MAX(`table_view_name`.`production_count`) AS `production_count`
FROM `table_view_name`
GROUP BY `table_view_name`.`part_id`)
```

But here, although all columns and their values have been segregated, the data type for each column is varchar only. So here my only question is, Can I change the data type of a column in pivot table? If so, How could it be?

Comment: Use cast (column_name as data_type). Make sure that column you are converting should have appropiate value as per data type

Comment: When employing an EAV model, I like to split the attributes out to different tables according to data type. So, I'll have a table of date attributes, a table of integer attributes, decimal attributes, and strings. That way you retain sql's data type functionality.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Could you be more specific in terms of query syntax I've used in the above?

Comment: @Strawberry Got it. That would work. Thank you for your answer. But I'm going to have huge data in reality and lot more entities are going to take part in relations. Would you approach be robust with larger number of columns and retrievals of it?

Comment: I don't see why it would be any worse than your model - although a properly normalised schema would be the best scenario.

Comment: @Strawberry I agree. I'm going to try with yours model. Thank you :)